# Upgrade Konahrik to legendary?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've just finished the quest of the 8 Dragon Priest mask and got Konahrik.

But when I want to upgrade it at the forge, I can only go to Perfect. Can't it go to Legendary ?

I'm 100 in forge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The table shows what quality improvement an item will achieve based on
>   smithing level and if the smithing perk for the item is taken or not.
>   You can continue to improve on items once they reach Legendary, but
>   the description will not change.

```
Quality             Skill Required     Effect  
            Without Perk    With Perk   Armor   Other
Fine             14             14        +2     +1
Superior         31             22        +6     +3
Exquisite        65             40        +10    +5
Flawless         100            57        +13    +7
Epic             134            74        +17    +8
Legendary        168            91        +20    +10
```

[Source](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Smithing#Weapon_and_Armor_Improvement)

> Smithing skills higher than 100 can be attained using "Fortify Smithing" equipment and potions, thus allowing any item to be made Epic or Legendary.

[Source](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Smithing)

Comment: The first sentence is incorrect. Enchanted gear is not in any way different from non-enchanted gear for purposes of smithing, except for requiring the Arcane Smithing perk. The problem is that some unique items lack a material keyword, which means they do not benefit from %material% smithing perks. If you're playing on PC, you can get mods that fix that problem, check the Skyrim Nexus.

Comment: @kotekzot I removed the first sentence. I didn't knew about that, thanks =)

Comment: Thank you, I managed to do it with enchanted stuff and elixir. Thank :)

Comment: @Axiol I am happy about it, if you need anything else, just come and ask =) we are glad in help a fellow gamer =)

Answer (score 0):

konahrik the final dragon priest mask is able that i know of so far to be upgraded to 82-85(can't fully remember)armor points and when low on health will have a chance of healing you,summoning a dragon priest that is bound to you,raising the dead around you to fight for you and pushing back enemies